# Polymorphism and type-safety with "decoupled" classes

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, polymorphism, instanceof

In my code, I have certain types of classes for different photo collection types and each comes with a service class that manages it (due to the architecture of the overall application, I've to stick to that).

That's the code in a simplified version:

```js
interface ICollection {}

class ImportedCollection implements ICollection {}
class CustomCollection implements ICollection {}

class ImportedCollectionsService {
  findPhotos(collection: ImportedCollection) {
    console.log('ImportedCollectionsService.findPhotos');
  }
}
class CustomCollectionsService {
  findPhotos(collection: CustomCollection) {
    console.log('CustomCollectionsService.findPhotos');
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const importedCollectionsService = new ImportedCollectionsService();
const customCollectionsService = new CustomCollectionsService();

const collection: ICollection = new ImportedCollection();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (collection instanceof ImportedCollection) {
  importedCollectionsService.findPhotos(collection);
} else if (collection instanceof CustomCollection) {
  customCollectionsService.findPhotos(collection);
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ydp7xn?file=index.ts

It works and it's theoretically type-safe, but I'm not happy with the `instanceof` at the end of the snippet. Instead, I'd like to go for a more polymorphism-oriented approach for more flexibility (i.e. to have all code for a specific collection type at the same place).

Ideally, I'd get rid of the `instanceof` check entirely, but I don't know if that's even possible. Alternatively, a solution that at least encapsulates the check would be acceptable.

I tried around a bit and got to this code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vo5yb1
By using a (generic) interface, I can enforce all service classes to implement the `findPhotos` method with a collection-specific parameter, but I lose type-safety in line 40 (`collection` being casted to `any`).

If I let `findPhotos` accept a parameter of type `ICollection` instead, I'd just move the type-safety issue into the `findPhotos` method (which needed to do a type assertion as I need the more-specialized collection type within the method).

Is there a TypeScript feature or better architecture that allows me to fix these problems or should I better just stick to the original version).

Best regards

Comment: Can you turn your collection classes into a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) instead of just `ICollection`?

Comment: You're talking about something like https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yab9ek?

I'm not sure if that works, because there are properties on one collection type that don't exist on others.